# Android I am getting error in eclipse Juno while opening UI Editor

Tags: android, eclipse

While opening Activity UI editor, I am getting following errors

***Message***

```
activity_main.xml: Could not find bool resource matching value 0x111000C (resolved name: config_ui_enableFadingMarquee) in current configuration.
```

***stack trace***

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not find bool resource matching value 0x111000C (resolved name: config_ui_enableFadingMarquee) in current configuration.
    at android.content.res.BridgeResources.throwException(BridgeResources.java:693)
    at android.content.res.BridgeResources.getBoolean(BridgeResources.java:461)
    at android.view.ViewConfiguration.<init>(ViewConfiguration.java:315)
    at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:337)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:416)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:93)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:225)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:440)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1545)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1302)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.reloadLayoutSwt(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1777)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.access$0(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1715)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener$1.run(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1709)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the API level in GUI Editor... SOmeTimes that help...

OtherWise try restarting or Updating your Eclipse and SDK

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does tend to make your life hard sometimes.

Try restarting eclipse. If that does not work, try restarting your whole system.

If you still face the same problem, I guess you should just remove this version and download a fresh version of the ADT Bundle.

Comment: I already tried  first 2 things.... third one is really bad alternative for me :(

Comment: Sometimes, I feel eclipse is not at all stable. It gives abrupt errors and many times solution is to redo everything. :(

Comment: Well, I do agree with you that eclipse can really be painful sometimes. But until Android Studio goes out of beta, this is the best (but not the only) option that you have.

Comment: And instead of redoing everything, trying to ***clean*** the project. That usually takes care of the "abrupt errors" that you are talking about.

Comment: On the top of the GUI editor, you would find the API version specification. Try setting it to some other API level than the current one.